# How should the phrase "thank you" be written in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, nouns, compound-adjectives, style-manuals, compound-words

According to prevalent formal writing style rules,

- Should the phrase be in quotes (as in "thank you" or thank you)?
- Should T of Thank be capital?
- Should there be a hyphen?

> They did not give him a polite "thank you."

or,

> They did not give him a polite Thank-you.

or,

> They did not give him a polite "Thank you."

or,

> They did not give him a polite thank-you.

etc.

Comment: I feel this could be fairly easily answered with a little research. Have you done much so far?

Comment: Anything that I found about it, is actually not dispositive. the thank-you is a noun, but whether there should be quotes or not, T should be capital or not, or hyphen needed or not seems unclear.

Answer (score -2):

They did not give him a polite thank you. >> without the hyphen, I believe; it's not an adjective.

Rather rephrase:

Comment: It's a noun in the sentence in the OP. So hyphen should be good. But the real issue I think is quotes or not, T capital or not.